# Script stops executing after initial scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This script stops executing after the initial scroll. How do I make the script run every time I scroll?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adnLX/)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var xx = $("#bottom").position().top;

     $("#title").html(xx);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(window).scroll(function(){
        var xx = $('body').scrollTop();       
         $("#title").text(xx);
     });
});
```

You're [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrodriguezr/adnLX/1/) updated